# How to iterate a python dictionary (d = {}) starting with index s

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary and I need to iterate the dictionary starting with index s (not the first). I write so

```
def _get_cell_end_offset(self, d, s, n):
        for e in d[s:]:
            if e != 0 and d[e][0][1] == ".ends" and d[s][1][1] == n:
                return e
```

dictionary created so this `d = {}`, I added elements so `d[i] = l`

But in the result there is an error like

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 23, in <module>
    ss = netlist._get_cell_end_offset(s, 9, "NR2_V20_2")
  File "/home/ubuntu/synop/net.py", line 16, in _get_cell_end_offset
    for e in d[s:]:
TypeError: unhashable type"
```

My dictionary of this type

```
(1, [['START', '.SUBCKT'], ['PIN', 'NR2_V20_1'], ['PIN', 'VDD'], ['PIN', 'VSS'], ['PIN', 'VBP'], ['PIN', 'VBN'], ['PIN', 'X'], ['PIN', 'A1'], ['PIN', 'A2']])
(2, [['ELEMENT', 'R1'], ['PIN', 'X:F93'], ['PIN', 'X:195'], ['PIN', '6.014590e+00']])
(3, [['ELEMENT', 'Cg15'], ['PIN', 'ln_N_76:291'], ['PIN', 'VSS'], ['PIN', '2.133320e-17']])
.........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
```

What to do?

Comment: You're using the wrong datastructure here, dictionaries don't support indexing/slicing and they are unordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries are unsorted in python. This is because dictionaries are hash tables, and they are "ordered" according to the index hash. As such, they also cannot be sliced (i.e. `seq[i:j]`) like lists or strings can. In more technical words, dictionaries are *Mappings* whereas lists, strings, tuples, etc. are *Sequence* types. Only types derived from Sequences can be sliced.

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) for that purpose. It remembers in which order the items were added to the dictionary and allows you to iterate over it like a list.

Or probably just a list in the case of your specific example.

Comment: I corrected here so d1 = collections.OrderedDict (), but still the same error appears

Comment: You cannot slice the `OrderedDict` directly. Like for accessing dictionary elements, you need to use `.values()`, `.keys()` or `.items()` first. The difference is that these views are ordered. For example, `for key, value in d1.items()[s:]`

Answer (score 0):

Indexes of a dict is unordered because they are hash tables. If you want to iterate it from a certain key, I suggest you create a function "cmp" to define an order.

```
def cmp(a,b):
    if a<b:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

d={ i:1.0/i for i in range(1,10) }

for i in sorted(d.keys(),cmp)[3:]:
    print i,d[i]
```

Here is an example. Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: That cmp function is pointless. The work is being done by `sorted` here, and would work just as well just as `for i in sorted(d.keys())[3:]:`.

Comment: Daniel Roseman   Thank you so much for sorted(d.keys())[3:] you helped me a lot, this is just what I needed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, No, cmp function is important. You can just remove it and use sorted only. See what will happen. Hope you accept my answer.